# Blackberry: Submit app. What do I need in terms of signing?

Tags: blackberry

I'm about ready to submit my app to app world, however I'm not exactly clear as to what I need.

So far, I've been working with the .cod file to test on my device. Is that all I need? I have signed the cod using the signing keys, however I'm not sure how these keys associate with my vendor account. Do they even need to be associated? I know the signing keys form is separate from the vendor account, so is it only tied by the company name I had to input?

The vendor account also mention JAD files. I've never even heard of these files. I can't find clear documentation as to what I should do, only the process in which they evaluate the app.

Sorry if I have overlooked the obvious.

Comment: I'd also need to know this, although I've not gotten my account verified just yet. :-)

Comment: What I need to submit is not clear. I need bundle folders and multiples cod? Is that only if they are uniquely different?

Comment: I just tried uploading my cod file in a bundle created in their web app, and it uploaded myapp-1.cod, myapp-2.cod etc... is that supposed to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to submit your main COD file. You dont have to upload multiple cod files unless you have different cod files for different builds.

Comment: When I submit my main .cod file it automatically uploads a multitude of cods. Like myapp-1.cod, myapp-2.cod etc... is that normal?

Comment: Yes it is normal. The main COD file is split into sibling cod files which are less than 64K in size. This is to allow OTA (Over the air install) of COD files.